# How to filter JSON array which has the same id?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

My JSON data be like:

```
{
  "Data":
    [
      {"ID": A1,"Function": A,"Status": 1},
      {"ID": A1,"Function": B,"Status": 0},
      {"ID": A1,"Function": C,"Status": 1},
      {"ID": A2,"Function": A,"Status": 0},
      {"ID": A2,"Function": B,"Status": 0},
      {"ID": A2,"Function": C,"Status": 2},
      {"ID": A3,"Function": A,"Status": 0},
      {"ID": A3,"Function": B,"Status": 0}
    ]
}
```

This is what I want:

```
{
  "Data":
    [
      {"ID": A1,"Status": 1},
      {"ID": A2,"Status": 2},
      {"ID": A3,"Status": 0}
    ]
}
```

I have so many duplicate IDs while I only need one ID with a maximum of Status.
I just don't know where to start with. Could anyone give me some tips?

Comment: `.filter()` method combined with an array of duplicates for filtering, at least that's how I'd do it

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Comment: This is ambiguous. How does your program knows which ID to select. For example why your output contains id a1 with status 1 and not status 0

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Sorry, I've edited it. I think it doesn't matter so I just ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) as reference to the index of the result array with the same `ID` and check if the actual `Status` is smaller, then update the array.

```js
var data = [{ ID: 'A1', Status: 1 }, { ID: 'A1', Status: 0 }, { ID: 'A1', Status: 1 }, { ID: 'A2', Status: 0 }, { ID: 'A2', Status: 0 }, { ID: 'A2', Status: 2 }, { ID: 'A3', Status: 0 }, { ID: 'A3', Status: 0 }],
    map = new Map,
    filtered = [];

data.forEach(function (o) {
    var index = map.get(o.ID);               // get index
    if (index === undefined) {               // if no index available
        map.set(o.ID, filtered.push(o) - 1); // push object and store index in map
        return;                              // exit early
    }
    if (filtered[index].Status < o.Status) { // check status
        filtered[index] = o;                 // update array
    }
});

console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Without `Map`

```js
var data = [{ ID: 'A1', Status: 1 }, { ID: 'A1', Status: 0 }, { ID: 'A1', Status: 1 }, { ID: 'A2', Status: 0 }, { ID: 'A2', Status: 0 }, { ID: 'A2', Status: 2 }, { ID: 'A3', Status: 0 }, { ID: 'A3', Status: 0 }],
    filtered = data.reduce(function (r, o) {
        var index = r.findIndex(({ ID }) => ID === o.ID);
        if (index === -1) {
            r.push(o);
            return r;
        }
        if (r[index].Status < o.Status) {
            r[index] = o;
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, It does work! Could you tell me what `filtered.push(o) - 1` means? Why `-1`? (Sorry I'm a newbie)

Comment: never mind to ask. `push` returns the new length of the array and for getting the index, you need to subtract one because indices are zero based.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#reduce` and create an object with `ID` and `Status` and replace the value of `Status` if the value is less than the stored value. Extract out all the values from the object using `Object#values()`.

```js
var data = { "Data": [ {"ID": "A1","Function": "A","Status": 1}, {"ID": "A1","Function": "B","Status": 0}, {"ID": "A1","Function": "C","Status": 1}, {"ID": "A2","Function": "A","Status": 0}, {"ID": "A2","Function": "B","Status": 0}, {"ID": "A2","Function": "C","Status": 2}, {"ID": "A3","Function":"A","Status": 0}, {"ID": "A3","Function": "B","Status": 0} ] },
    result = Object.values(data.Data.reduce((r,{ID, Status}) => {
      if(ID in r ) {
        if (r[ID].Status < Status)
          r[ID].Status = Status;
      } else {
        r[ID] = {ID, Status};
      }
      return r;
    },{}));
var output = {Data: result};
console.log(output);
```